# Using Oracle Berkeley DB with Xcode

Tags: xcode, oracle, berkeley-db

I just recently installed Berkeley DB 6.0.30 so that I could use it in a server-side app that I plan to write. I got past the install via Terminal, but now I need a bit of help making the headers accessible within Xcode so that the app that I build is actually usable.

Here's the [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/tonatiuh/wiki/InstallingBerkeleyDBForMac) that I followed.

Where it gets me though is that I don't have a whole lot of experience operating from the command-line and the guide seems tailored for an Eclipse utilization, which obviously doesn't do me many favors being constrained within Xcode for the Mac app development.

Anyone know how to make the header path known to Xcode?

Comment: So where are the files installed?

Comment: I specified that the configuration prefix be `/usr/local` so I'd assume the headers are under `/usr/local/include`. Checking in Finder confirms that the `db_cxx.h` header I'm looking for is there.

Comment: You just need to add `/usr/local/include` to the *Header Search Path* then.

Comment: I see that I can do that from individual project settings/configuration, but is there a way to make that "global"; that is, such that Xcode knows the path from default so I don't have to write that path into every project I wish to use the DB in?

Comment: I don't believe so, no.  At least I have never chanced upon it.

Comment: Alright, that's fine. You should post the Header Search Path comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `/usr/local/include` to the *Header Search Path*, so the compiler can find the header files.